# Change color of legend on input focus

Tags: html, css

Is there any way with CSS for changing color of legend text when input gets the focus, similar to fieldset working?

Each of the fieldset changes color when their particular input gets the focus. I am trying similarly for legend.

```css
fieldset {
  border-radius: 0.6vh;
  border: 1vh solid black;
  padding: 1.68vh;
}

fieldset:focus-within {
  border-color: blue;
}

/* legend not changing color when focused on input */

legend:focus-within {
  color: blue;
}

legend {
  padding: 0 1.2vh;
  color: black;
}

input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.29vh;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: black;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Name</legend>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: focus-within senses when there is an element getting focus and is within the element with that proprty. Your input is not within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the event from the input focus and select with `>` the legend text and change color.

```css
fieldset {
    border-radius: 0.6vh;
    border: 1vh solid black;
    padding: 1.68vh;
}

fieldset:focus-within {
    border-color: blue;
}

/* legend not changing color when focused on input */
fieldset:focus-within > legend {
    color: blue;
}

legend {
    padding: 0 1.2vh;
    color: black;
}

input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0.29vh;
}

input::placeholder {
    color: black;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Name</legend>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
</fieldset>
```